# Finding most occuring substring in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, substring

I have a long list of sub-stings that I want to search through and find how many times two particular sub-stings occur. The following code is what I have started:

```
dataA = ['0000000001001000',
'0000000010010001',
'0000000100100011',
'0000001001000100',
'0000010010001010',
'0000100100010100',
'0001001000101011',
'0010010001010110']
A_vein_1 = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
joined_A_Search_1 = ''.join(map(str,A_vein_1))
print 'search 1', joined_A_Search_1
A_vein_2 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
joined_A_Search_2 = ''.join(map(str,A_vein_2))
print 'search 2', joined_A_Search_2
match_A = []    #empty list to append closest match to
#Match search algorithm
for text in dataA:
    if joined_A_Search_1 == text:
        if joined_A_Search_2 == dataA[text+1[:-1]]:
        print 'logic stream 1'
        match_A.append(dataA[text+1[-1]])    
if joined_A_Search_2 == text[:-1]:
    print 'logic stream 2'
    #print 'match', text[:-1]
    match_A.append(text[-1])
print 'matches', match_A
try:
    filter_A = max(set(match_A), key=match_A.count) #finds most frequent
except:
    filter_A = 0 #defaults 0
    print 'no match A'
filter_A = int(filter_A)
print '0utput', filter_A
```

It is important to note that A_vein_1 is 16 characters long and A_vein_2 is only 15 charters long, and thus the resaon for the search. The line that I am having trouble with is:

```
 if joined_A_Search_2 == dataA[text+1[:-1]]:
```

What I want to do is look for A_vein_1, if it is there, look at the next sequence under it to see if the first 15 charters match A_vein_2, if so append to the list, if not, search for only A_vein_2. If that is not found, then the it will default to zero. I believe that I have the right idea, but wrong syntax with this if statement. I have been learning Python for the past few months, so I am not quite proficient yet. Note, that dataA has been shortened, and the A_veins have been substituted in manually for the purpose of this post, and the prints are to track errors.

Comment: Ok, let's say you have list of ['1','1','1','2','2','3','3'] what is expected result, because I find your question difficult to understand

Comment: @MarkoMackic For this particular application the form is only 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like the following.  It sounds like you want to check the next item after a match against the first search.

```
for i,text in enumerate(dataA):
    if joined_A_Search_1 == text:
        if joined_A_Search_2 == dataA[i+1][:-1]:
            print 'logic stream 1'
            match_A.append(dataA[i+1][-1])
```

`enumerate` returns both the index and content of what you are iterating over, so to check the next item you can do `dataA[i+1]`.  You'll need to handle the condition of the first search matching the last item, because then `data[i+1]` is undefined, but this should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: This appears to be doing what I was trying to do. I am testing different sequences on the bigger list right now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It performs exactly what I wanted to achieve. Next time, I will keep enumerate in my back pocket. Thanks again.